# Adding paragraph element(html p) id as paraId from docx w:p when converting docx to html

Tags: html, docx4j

I am trying to convert docx to html where I want to have id for html paragraph element as equal to the corresponding paragraph element id (w:p -> paraId) from docx.

for example

```
<w:p w14:paraId="abcd">....</w:p> converted to <p id="abcd">...</p>
```

Above result is needed to find specific paragraph after conversion, How can we achieve this using docx4j or is there any alternate way available?

#edit - 1 : Seems some modification of code needed in XsltHTMLFunctions.createBlock